# can not launch node of type [robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf]: cannot locate node of type [robot_pose_ekf] in package [robot_pose_ekf]

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Melodic in Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM.

I tried uninstalling and the reinstalling the package from the git (as found in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf)), but ran into the same error. I was able to build the package using `rosbuild` and build the workspace using `catkin_make_isolated`

When I run the command: `roslaunch robot_pose_ekf robot_pose_ekf.launch` I get the following as my output:

```
parallels@parallels:~/autorobot_ws$ roslaunch robot_pose_ekf robot_pose_ekf.launch 
... logging to /home/parallels/.ros/log/3b031c06-9019-11ea-a883-001c42bcca12/roslaunch-parallels-7626.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://parallels:40787/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_pose_ekf/base_footprint_frame: base_footprint
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq: 30.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame: odom_combined
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout: 1.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used: True
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.5

NODES
  /
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf]: Cannot locate node of type [robot_pose_ekf] in package [robot_pose_ekf]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

---

I then ran `rosrun robot_pose_ekf wtf.py` as per some advice as suggested in the [troubleshooting guide](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf/Troubleshooting). I got the following as my output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/autorobot_ws/src/robot_pose_ekf/scripts/wtf.py", line 4, in <module>
    from robot_pose_ekf.srv import GetStatus, GetStatusRequest
ImportError: No module named robot_pose_ekf.srv
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351679/can-not-launch-node-of-type-%5Brobot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf%5D:-cannot-locate-node-of-type-%5Brobot_pose_ekf%5D-in-package-%5Brobot_pose_ekf%5D/) by [jkaplan1123](https://answers.ros.org/users/54507/jkaplan1123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check the usual suspects like sourcing the setup.bash file ?

---

Originally posted by [nihalsoans91](https://answers.ros.org/users/37719/nihalsoans91/) with karma: 21 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jkaplan1123](https://answers.ros.org/users/54507/jkaplan1123/) on 2020-05-07**:
Yes I have. I run `source ~/autorobot_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, downloading the `catkin tools` toolbox, running `catkin init` on my workspace followed by `catkin clean` and `catkin build` worked. I have no idea why, but it did. Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue in the future.

---

Originally posted by [jkaplan1123](https://answers.ros.org/users/54507/jkaplan1123/) with karma: 21 on 2020-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1